# Missing cached stylesheet for Magento 2 Theme

Tags: magento2, theme, css, less

We are using the free HiddenTechies theme "Bizkick" for our Magento 2 store and we are having an issue with a missing stylesheet.

On the front page, the theme is displaying correctly except for two blocks toward the bottom; the problem seems to be caused by a missing stylesheet.

In the browser console, I receive this error:

```
(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'https://our-magento-site.org/pub/static/version1591889861/frontend/Hiddentechies/bizkick/en_US/css/whitedemo.css' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

When I try to open https://our-magento-site.org/pub/static/version1591889861/frontend/Hiddentechies/bizkick/en_US/css/whitedemo.css in the browser, I get the following (php?) error message:

```
Compilation from source: LESS file is empty: frontend/Hiddentechies/bizkick/en_US/css/whitedemo.less
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\AlternativeSource->processContent('css/whitedemo.cs...', '', '', &Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File\FallbackContext#0000000036e858b600000000403d0061#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/PreProcessor/AlternativeSource.php:114]
#2 Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\AlternativeSource->process(&Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\Chain#0000000036e858aa00000000403d0061#) called at [vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Asset/PreProcessor/PreprocessorStrategy.php:76]
#3 Magento\Developer\Model\View\Asset\PreProcessor\PreprocessorStrategy->process(&Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\Chain#0000000036e858aa00000000403d0061#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/PreProcessor/Pool.php:77]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\Pool->process(&Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\Chain#0000000036e858aa00000000403d0061#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Source.php:152]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Source->preProcess(&Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File#0000000036e858b500000000403d0061#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Source.php:105]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Source->getFile(&Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File#0000000036e858b500000000403d0061#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/File.php:158]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/StaticResource.php:135]
#8 Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#9 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource#0000000036e8586700000000403d0061#) called at [pub/static.php:13]
</pre>
```

I have tried clearing the cache, as well as using these console commands but the issue hasn't been fixed:

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f`

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: I am having the same situation, I did all the static-content deploy like you above. the link of CSS content the same issue. Do you have any update how to get this resolve?